# Python/Connect-four minimax, first column piece placement Issue (School Project)

Tags: python, project

I am thoroughly confused. I created this connect-4 game using the mini-max algorithm for my school project. It works well, but there is an issue with the first column. Whenever I reach the top of the first column (array index 0), it won't allow me to place a piece there. It would ask again for the input and continues to do that until I choose a different column. When I pick a different column, it places two pieces in one turn. The algorithm does the same thing so it isn't a mini-max issue. Other columns do not have this problem.

Here is the code:
https://github.com/delandchen/connect-4-minimax-algorithm

[Example where I only place pieces in the first column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwTS9.png), the array in the image that looks like this [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] are the columns that you can place valid moves, I printed it for debugging.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is where you have

```
 if game.make_move(column, letter): # line 198, main.py
```

This will return 0 which is falsey.

Change it to be:

```
 if game.make_move(column, letter) is not False:
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thank you so much!!